# Extract floats from a String using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string

I am a real beginner in python, but I heard it should be easy in string manipulation. Can you tell me how to do that:

I have a String:

```
str = "[someString xpos=1024.0 ypos=768.0 someotherString]"
```

I'd like to extract the two float numbers from that string so that I cant use them as parameters for a function.

Is there a easy way where I can do like this?
In my mind it looks like this:

```
*xpos=____.__*ypos=____.___*
```

where:

```
*: Any char

_: float number, maybe with variable lenght
```

(Sorry my english is very bad, is there a manual in german for regular expression?)

regards

Comment: you can accept one of the answers if you found them good enough for your needs!

Comment: Thank you all for helping me!

Answer (score 6):

This one will work in case your `xpos` or `ypos` are negative:

```
x, y = map(float, re.findall(r'[+-]?[0-9.]+', str))
```

Comment: `?` instead of `*` would be better.

Comment: thank you! I've updated the answer! Also added a second `?` in case the string has something like `.5`...

Comment: Does it really work? I'm getting `['=1024', '.0', '=768', '.0']` as a result of `findall`.

Comment: Thank you, my last edit do add the second `?` was wrong.. I returned to the original post...

Comment: One problem with this is it only picks up numbers that have a decimal point in them.

Comment: This seems to work on floats and decimals: `re.findall(r'[+-]?[0-9.]+', str)`

Comment: @Bill thank you for the feedback, I updated the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple regular expression to find floating point numbers.

```js
/[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/
```

[Demo](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5b-%2B%5d%3F%5b0-9%5d%2a.%3F%5b0-9%5d%2B&input=%5bsomeString%20xpos%3D1024.0%20ypos%3D768.0%20someotherString%5d)

Comment: This is not JS, you may remove the `g` modifier

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "[someString xpos=1024.0 ypos=768.0 someotherString]"
>>> results = re.findall('pos=([\d.]+)', s)
>>> results
['1024.0', '768.0']
>>> map(float, results)
[1024.0, 768.0]
```

Comment: Let's also match all the consecutive dots `...` !

Comment: Well, true, but, usually, the expression depends on what kind of input/text is there.

Answer (score 0):

You'll can use the re module.

```
import re

matchobject = re.search(string, "[.+xpos=(.+)\sypos=(.+)\s.+]")
xpos = matchobject.group(1)
ypos = matchobject.group(2)
```

here '.+' means any set of characters of variable length until you reach the next pattern specified. The parentheses are used to group the xpos and ypos values so you can extract them later.

it will return xpos and ypos as strings, you can convert to float or int.

```
xpos = int(xpos)
ypos = float(ypos)
```